# Issue removing event listener from element in react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, redux, event-listener

On my react-redux webpage, I am making use of some even listeners: some are attached to window, but the touchstart and touchend are attached to a specific element (an image). The ones attached to window I can remove just fine, but for the others I get a an error message after I have loaded a new page.

The error message is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeEventListener' of null`

The code looks something like this

```
class ImageClick extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            lastClick: [0, 0],
        }
        this.tX = null
        this.tY = null
        this.x0 = null
        this.y0 = null

        this.readDims = this.readDims.bind(this);
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
        this.handleOrientationChange = this.handleOrientationChange.bind(this);
        this.handleMouseUp = this.handleMouseUp.bind(this);


    componentDidMount(){
        window.addEventListener("orientationchange", this.handleOrientationChange)
        document.getElementById('target-image').addEventListener("touchstart", this.handleClick)
        document.getElementById('target-image').addEventListener("touchend", this.handleMouseUp)
        this.initialize()
    }

    componentWillUnmount(){
        window.removeEventListener("orientationchange", this.handleOrientationChange);
        document.getElementById('target-image').removeEventListener("touchstart", this.handleClick)
        document.getElementById('target-image').removeEventListener("touchend", this.handleMouseUp)
    }
    
    readDims() {
        console.log("reading dims...")
        this.tX = document.getElementById('target-image').width
        this.tY = document.getElementById('target-image').height
        var rect = document.getElementById('target-image').getBoundingClientRect()
        this.x0 = rect.left
        this.y0 = rect.top
    }
    
    render(){
        const {classes} = this.props
        return (
            <div id="main-screen" className={classes.main_screen}>
                <img id='target-image' onLoad={this.readDims} className={classes.main_image} src={photo} alt={""}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Comment: I would look at using the relevant React synthetic events [Touch Events](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#touch-events)

Comment: Error reproduced on codepen would be helpful